# How to check if a number (or str) from a list is in another column? - Python

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a problem cross-checking numbers between a list and a column.

I have a list called "allowed_numbers" with 40 different phone numbers and a column imported from an excel sheet with 8000 calls called df['B-NUMBER']. I believe around 90% of these 8000 calls are in the allowed_number list but I need to cross-check this somehow and be able to see what numbers that isn't in the list. preferably store these numbers in a variable called "fraud"

So I made the allowed_numbers to a list with strings inside, it looks like this.

```
'21114169202',
 '27518725605',
 '514140099453',
 '5144123173905',
```

```
allowed_number=re.sub(",","", allowed_number)
allowed_number = allowed_number.split(" ")
```

Then I tried to cross-check this with the column df['B-NUMBER'] in different ways but nothing works and need help. I've tried this

```
 df[df['B-NUMBER'].isin(allowed_number)]
```

```
 fraud = [df['B-NUMBER'] in allowed_number if allowed_number not in df["B-NUMBER"]]
```

```
fraud = df['B-NUMBER'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(y for y in x if y not in allowed_number))
```

I try to avoid loops because of the run time but if it is possible with a loop somehow please share your insight :) cheers

Comment: It's a bit hard to check without the exact example, but I would expect that `df["B-number"].isin(allowed_number)` should give you the array of booleans that you are interested in. Check if `allowed_number` and `B-number` are both of the same type (i.e. both `int` or both `str`). Could you post some entries of the dataframe and the output of calling `.isin`?

Comment: ``df["B-NUMBER"].isin(allowed_number)`` gives me booleans however these are ``false`` which I find strange as the majority should be ``true``. Allowed _number is a list and the numbers in that list is a string ``type(allowed_number[1]`` gives ``str`` and the column is numpy.int64.

Comment: If you print `allowed_number` and `df["B-NUMBER"]`, are they both strings? Or both integers? Maybe the datatype is the problem. You could try adding `allowed_number = [int(x) for x in allowed_number]` to convert your allowed numbers to integers (if that's the data type in the `df`).

Comment: You are a life save Thomas, converting ``allowed_numbers`` to ``int`` instead of ``str`` gives me ``true`` boolean numbers which makes more sense. Sorry I updated my first answer while you wrote before. Is there an easy way to store the ``false`` values in another variable?

Comment: I added an answer that addresses the extraction of the fraudulent numbers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to summarize the discussion in the comments.
Using

```
df['B-NUMBER'].isin(allowed_number)
```

works once the content of `allowed_number` is turned into integers via

```
allowed_number = [int(x) for x in allowed_number]
```

So to get the fraudulent numbers something like this works

```
allowed_number=re.sub(",","", allowed_number)
allowed_number = allowed_number.split(" ")
allowed_number = [int(x) for x in allowed_number]

df["allowed"] = df["B-NUMBER"].isin(allowed_number)

# fraudulent 
df_fradulent = df.loc[~df["allowed"]]
```

Comment: Good summarize, I am probably missing something with the extraction of the fraudulent numbers. ``df_fradulent = df.loc[!df["allowed"]]`` gives syntax error. Is it possible to save the numbers that give off ``false value`` and not the index placement? if you catch my drift

Comment: Sorry, it should of course be a "~" instead of the "!" in the last row. I'll edit my post.